# Ruby syntax: What does the '<' single less than mean in Ruby besides 'less than'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to learn Ruby on Rails and have been trying to install the "Devise" gem for authorization on my website. In doing so, I ran across this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :confirmable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

What does the '<' mean in this context? What is it doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, this is the **inheritance** operator, which use can be simply demonstrated with this example:

```
class Ancestor
  def meth
    puts "ancestor"
  end
end

class AnotherClass < Ancestor
end

a = AnotherClass.new
a.meth # displays ancestor
```

Here, the `AnotherClass` class effectively possesses all instance methods defined in the `Ancestor` class.

Answer (score 3):

`<` in this context is defining an `inheritance` between `User` class and `ActiveRecord::Base` class where `ActiveRecord::Base` is the parent class and `User` is the child class.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `<` Syntax for subclassing.

```
  class Bar
    def test
      puts 'Testing!'
    end
  end

  class Foo < Bar
  end
```

Now `Foo` is a subclass of `Bar`, and has all methods available.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `User` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it means `less than` even here. Ruby says, that since `User` class is inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` and it is it's child class, so it is less than `ActiveRecord::Base`.

However, There are several other places where it is used, like inserting an element into an array.

```
[1,2,3] << 4 ## [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance! Also I don't think you should be learning Rails without first knowing what "<" does :)

Comment: I can't see why learning ruby while learning it in the specific context of the Rails framework would be a bad idea. I'm assuming Rails has a lot of best practices built into it that are somewhat useful to learn.

Comment: I am not saying you have to be "good" at Ruby before you dive into Rails (Though that's what I believe) but I think operators come under the bare minimum, right? ^_^